# О баксах и памперсах

Tags: грамотная-речь

Мы привыкли к тому, что на сленге доллар называется "бакс". Но ведь на самом деле это множественное число, а в единственном числе будет "бак". Та же ситуация, насколько я знаю, обстоит со словом "памперс". И насколько вообще грамотно после этого говорить "баксы" или "памперсы"? Это ведь получается как бы множественный род от множественного рода.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ИСТОРИЯ СЛОВ

Общеизвестное сейчас название доллара «бакс» произошло от buck (англ.), что в переводе означает «олень». Именно рога и шкуры оленей служили денежным эквивалентом в Великобритании. А так как новые переселенцы, обживающие Американский континент в массе своей были англичане, то и слово это прижилось в Новом Свете.
http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/147335-pochemu-dollary-nazyvajut-baksami.html

Первые одноразовые подгузники были выпушены в конце 50-х годов компанией "Procter & Gamble" под торговой маркой "Pampers" - от английского слова "pamper" ("баловать" или "лелеять", "изнеживать"). Название говорит само за себя: памперсы были призваны баловать мам и облегчать им жизнь. С тех пор около 95% американцев и 98% европейцев пользуются этим полезным изобретением, предпочитая изделия разных производителей. А памперс стал именем нарицательным.
http://www.livemaster.ru/topic/292879-pochemu-pampers-nazyvaetsya-pampersom

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Истории заимствованных слов могут быть разными. Закрепляясь в русском языке, они приобретают определенную фонетическую и графическую форму, и именно эти формы считаются грамотными. Называть "бакс" "баком" неудобно, такое слово уже  есть в языке. Поэтому копируется форма мн. числа "баксы", и уже от нее образуется форма ед. числа "бакс". А слово "памперс" к мн.числу отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 3):

От живого донора пациенту пересадили печень. Как донор влияет на функционирование орган после операции? Никак. Так же и в языке. После того как слово прижилось, язык-донор на слово уже не влияет. Если в русском бакс - единственное число, то нет никакой разницы какое число это в английском.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, слово бакс -ед.число. А мн.ч. - баксы, а не баки. Бакс - мн.число в анг.языке.Дело в том, что русский язык заимствовал  это слово в мн.ч. По всей вероятности, правила образования мн.ч. в анг. языке им были не знакомы , это слово восприняли за ед.ч. и поэтому мн.ч. было образовано с применением русских правил.